# Save dialog state info

Tags: android, dialog

In my app I have an "info" that show a dialog, when I change orientation of emulator I lose that dialog. So I learned how save instance:

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("dialog", ChangeLogs);
}

protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    if(savedInstanceState.containsKey("dialog")){
        ChangeLogs(); // this is methos that show dialog
    }
}
```

Now every times I change orientation I see the dialog (obviously this occur because there is not any check if dialog is show or no).

I can't continue. What I will do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `DialogFragment` so you never think of that saving state again

Comment: @Poll Hallen Why, you can use the android compatibility library